# MVC Action has missing data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, actionmethod

I send my viewmodel from my get action method to a view for update, the view has a submit button which takes returns control to the post action method.  The viewmodel is of this form

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public someObject a;
   public someOtherObject b;
}
```

Now, in the get method `someOtherObject b` has data in it, in the view it has data in it, but in the post method it is null.  Why might this be?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you bind the property in your view? Can you post a part of your view?

Comment: Provide some details about your view please.

Comment: @Styxxy code posted - actually, I have another problem also.

Comment: How are you calling the action in the view? How are you passing the parameters? The code you have posted has strictly nothing to do with the model class you have shown.

Comment: Using this <div class="buttonwrapper">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
                </div>

Comment: Please post your real model. As well as the controller.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov any idea?

Comment: Your model and view don't match the question being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking into it in too much detail, I'd take a guess at the problem being that your model has fields instead of properties. Try this instead:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public someObject a { get; set; }
   public someOtherObject b { get; set; }
}
```

The default MVC model binder examines your model for settable properties (hence the overridable [`SetProperty()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder.setproperty.aspx) method taking a `PropertyDescriptor`) and sets those values, so I'm guessing that fields are ignored.

Comment: Then do you need to update your question? Because on your question they're fields.